# Create new link with the name of php array

Tags: php, html

I have this question. Is there any way to generate a link with the productName of each element of the array. Can I use different programming languages?

I have this array

```
<?php
$products = array(
    "hoodie" => array(
        "productName" => "Red hoodie",
        "productPrice" => "19.34"
    ),
    "T-shirt" => array(
        "productName" => "T-shirt",
        "productPrice" => "12.58"
    )
);
?>
```

And they are displaying on my html page like this

```
<?php foreach($products as $product){?>
    <div class="product">
        <div class="productName"><?php echo $product['productName'];?></div>
        <div class="productPrice"><?php echo $product['productPrice'];?></div>
    </div>
<?php } ?>
```

And I want to make that it generates link with the name of product and wrap it around the product div. And in that link it puts all the information whats in that products array. Example for hoodie div it generates the link with its name `red-hoodie.php` (or `red_hoodie.php`) and in that link it shows the name and price and description (thats in the hoodie array) like in every eCommerce website.

Comment: `<php` is that what you really have? There's a ? missing here. And why the javascript/jquery tags?

Comment: I just asked if that is possible. If it is how. And can use different programming languages, but it just gets the information from php array.

Comment: You didn't really answer my question but someone added the missing ? for `<php` as in `<?php`. Why different programming languages? That makes this too broad. If you want to generate hyperlinks, use an `href`.

Comment: You should just add a url slug to the array, this will save you having to do string operations e.g. replacing spaces, dashes etc. - just like in every e-commerce website.

Comment: At least add an anchor tag....

Comment: You need to be clear about exactly what you want.  Using the sample inputs (array) given above, please provide the desired output.

Comment: Your question says _"with the name of php array"_ but it's not the name of the _**array**_ you describe, it is the `productName` of each _element_ of the array you are using.  Please re-phrase your question title.

Answer (score 0):

First your link in html is going to look like this.

```
<a href="<?= str_replace(' ', '-', $product['productName']);?>"."php"><?= $product['productName'] ?> </a>
```

Then to make the page list data of the product dynamically, use PHP globals like $_SERVER to get name from URL and query your data accordingly.

Check $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']

I hope I got your question properly.